# Visual Studio project history locations?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to find the 12th (approximately) most recent project opened by VS2008?  I know you get a list of the last four or five in the recent projects tab, but I was hoping it was possible to find a longer list buried somewhere...

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

File, recent projects.  If it's only showing 4 or 5 then go to Tools, Options and under Environment, select General and modify the # in the recent files section.